# struct fill with values

Tags: c++, struct

### EDIT 2: regarding the XY Problem:

In a binary protocol I need to send 8 bytes. These bytes can contain integers that are 8 or 16 bit long, but also flags of 1, 2 or 3 bit length.

To simplify it, I'd prefer to use a struct:

```
struct MakeCoffeeCmd
{
    UINT8 sugar : 2;
    UINT8 milk : 1;
    UINT16 liters;
};
```

so I can use it like this:

```
cmd.sugar = 1;
cmd.milk = 0;
cmd.liters = 42;

send(cmd);
```

Problem is: sugar, milk and liters have defined positions in the 8 byte array, every unused bit must be set to 1.

For now, I use:

```
UINT8 cmd[8];
memset(&cmd, ~0, sizeof(cmd));

cmd[1] &= sugar << 4;
cmd[1] &= milk << 1;
*((UINT16*)(cmd + 3)) = liters;

send(cmd);
```

### Original question:

I want to create an 8 byte long struct. For reasons, I only care about the second and third byte, all other bytes must be set to 0xFF.

It should look like this: 0xFF [Byte1] [Byte2] 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF

I tried like this, but it seems way too ugly.

```
struct mystruct
{
    mystruct() : should_be_ff(0xFF), should_also_be_ff(0xFF), sould_be_ff_too(0xFFFFFFFF) {}
    UINT8  should_be_ff;
    UINT16 important_values;
    UINT8  should_also_be_ff;
    UINT32 should_be_ff_too;
 }
```

I could use bit fields for filling, but then I'm not able to set the correct values.

I would prefer something like this:

```
struct mystruct
{
    0xFF;
    UINT16 important_values;
    0xFFFFFF;
}
```

Any ideas?

### Edit 1:

I need this for some proprietary binary protocol, which i cannot change. This is just an example, there are more complex structures with flags and bit fields. Using them in an array would be ugly.

I've modified packing to (hopefully) eliminate padding errors.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) can you explain *why* you need this?

Comment: In current C++ you can write `UINT8 should_be_ff = 0xff;`

Comment: What's ugly about it? Seems straightforward to me as-is with perhaps a comment.

Comment: Don't write `0xff`. Use `-1`.

Comment: Your struct won't be 8 bytes long. There will be padding added.

Comment: The struct is not guaranteed to be look like you imagine because the compiler might insert some padding to align the members. Check your compilers manual to find out how to tightly "pack" a struct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I want to create an 8 byte long struct.

Your struct probably isn't 8 bytes long. You'll have padding between members and possibly at the end.

There is no standard way to guarantee that the size of a struct is 8 bytes.

If you need exactly 8 bytes, you can use an array:

```
uint8_t arr[8];                    // exactly 8 bytes
memset(arr, ~0, sizeof arr);       // set all bits to 1 i.e. every byte to 0xff
uint16_t foo = 123u;               // some important 2-byte value
memcpy(arr + 1, &foo, sizeof foo); // copy the 2-byte value to the second and third index
```

Remember that the order of the bytes depend on the endianness of the architechture.

## Regarding edit 2:

You can certainly use a struct like that to represent the protocol message within your own application. But to send it according to a protocol, you must first convert it to an array. It must be done field-by-field. Casting won't do it correctly across platforms due to padding and aliasing concerns. I recommend using an array of `char` because `char` type has special rules regarding aliasing that make them easier to work with.

To set unused bits of your struct instance to 1, the simplest solution is probably `memset`:

```
MakeCoffeeCmd object;
memset(&object, ~0, sizeof object);
```

After that you can set the fields that are used. Then copy each field to their correct slots in the array.

Comment: That's the way I do it now. But then I've some problems with bigger structs and bit flags. Example
`arr[2] &= important_flag << 5;`

Comment: @Powerswitch If you already use an array, then you're already set because switching to a struct will only bring platform dependence. I don't see how using a struct would magically help you with bit flags.

Comment: @Powerswitch I updated my answer regarding your edit 2.

Answer (score 2):

With `gcc` you can do this, to enforce tight packing:

```
struct __attribute__((__packed__)) my_struct 
{
    uint8_t  field1=0xff;
    uint16_t field2=0xabcd; // or whatever you need
    uint8_t  field3=0xff;
    uint32_t field4=0xffffffff;
};
```

Have a look at the docs, for details on using `__attribute__`:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Type-Attributes.html#Common-Type-Attributes

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
struct mystruct
{
    UINT8 ignore1;
    std::array<UINT8, 2> data;
    std::array<UINT8, 5> ignore2;

    mystruct()
        : ignore1(0xFF)
    {
        ignore2.fill(0xFF);
    }
};
```

If std::array had a fill constructor then it would be even cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have something like this in mind:

```
struct mystruct{
 mystruct(uint16_t impval=0){
   memset(m_data,0xff,sizeof(m_data));
   important() = impval;
 }
 void* data(){
   return m_data;
 }
 uint16_t& important(){
   return *reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(m_data+1);
 }
private:
uint8_t m_data[8];
};
```

of course it could be made better and more portable but don't have the time atm

Answer (score 0):

what about this option:

```
 uint32_t arr[2];
 uint32_t inportant_flag = 123u;
 arr[0] = 0xFF0000FF + (inportant_flag<<8);
 arr[1] = 0xFFFFFFFF;
```